# MongoDb saving throws error for PHP class private members

Tags: php, mongodb

Greeting all,

I created a class in PHP that has a private member. And when I tried to save an instance of that class into  MongoDb, col->insert( $newObject ), the code throws the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?' in /var/www/html/index.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(105): MongoCollection->save(Object(Address)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 105

If i change the private member to public, it saves fine, but is there a way to keep it private, and not to be saved in the Mongodb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that returns an object without that property and insert it instead...